# How do I make my code read a specific column in Python?

Tags: python

For my first Python project I chose to make a trading algorithm. For this I have some information in Google Spreadsheets and have a certain column which contains values that determine whether I should buy or sell, I've downloaded this as a csv file and now I want to make my python code read that column instead of the 'close' column. I've tried to change all the 'close' terms with the term from my column name. I can't make it work, can someone help me with this?

This is what I used from the backtrader website:

```
class H_strategy(backtrader.Strategy):

    def log(self, txt, dt=None):
        ''' Logging function for this strategy'''
        dt = dt or self.datas[0].datetime.date(0)
        print('%s, %s' % (dt.isoformat(), txt))

    def __init__(self):
        # Keep a reference to the "close" line in the data[0] dataseries
        self.dataclose = self.datas[0].close
        self.order = None

    def notify_order(self, order):
        if order.status in [order.Submitted, order.Accepted]:
            return

        if order.status in [order.Completed]:
            if order.isbuy():
                self.log('BUY EXECUTED {}'.format(order.executed.price))
            elif order.issell():
                self.log('SELL EXECUTED {}'.format(order.executed.price))

            self.bar_executed = len(self)

        self.order = None

    def next(self):
        # Simply log the closing price of the series from the reference
        self.log('Close, %.2f' % self.dataclose[0])

        if self.order:
            return

        if not self.position:   
            if self.dataclose[0] < self.dataclose[-1]:
                # current close less than previous close

                if self.dataclose[-1] < self.dataclose[-2]:
                    # previous close less than the previous close

                    # BUY, BUY, BUY!!! (with all possible default parameters)
                    self.log('BUY CREATE, %.2f' % self.dataclose[0])
                    self.order = self.buy()
        else:
            if len(self) >= (self.bar_executed +5):
                self.log('SELL CREATED {}'.format(self.dataclose[0]))
                self.order = self.sell()
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question, you actually want to read a csv file, more specifically, only one column of the csv file.
You can use the `csv` module in python.

```
import csv
f = open("your_file_name.csv") # note that the file should be in the same directory as your main python file
reader = csv.reader(f)
for col1, col2, col3 in reader: # Here col1, col2, col3 are the names given to the columns in your csv file.
   Do_whatever_you_want_to_do
```